# Language support for recursive comments

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler-construction, recursion, comments

Most languages I've worked with don't have support for recursive comments.

1. Is there any reason why language designers would choose not to implement this?
2. Is it deceptively complex?
3. Would it have undesired results?

---

Example of a recursive comment:

```
/*
for (int j = 0; j <= SourceTexture.Height; j += SampleSize)
{
    ...
}

// Comment within comment below:
/*for (int i = 0; i < TextureColour.Length; i++)
{
    ...
}*/


sourceTexture.SetData<Color>(TextureColour);
*/
```

---

EDIT: I understand the argument of the answers so far (problems occur when you have comment tokens in strings). However, the reason for my confusion is that you have that problem now.

For example, i know the code below wouldn't give the expected result.

```
/*
    char *str = "/* string";
    // Are we now 1 level inside a comment or 2 levels?

*/

printf("Hello world");

/*
    char *str2 = "string */";
*/
```

But in my mind that's no different to an unexpected result in the case below:

```
/*
CODE "*/";
*/
```

Which would also yield an unexpected/undesired result.

So, while it could be a problem for recursive comments, my argument as to why that's not a reason not to do it, is that it is already a problem for non-recursive comments. As a programmer i know the compiler behaves like this and i work around it. I don't think it's much more effort to work around the same problem with recursive comments.

Comment: Why not go read an introductory text on compilers, then come back?

Comment: I understand the basics of compilers, but really only the basics (hence this question). Sorry if it is a simple one / should be obvious.

Comment: +1 because I always hated this. With modern editors it isn't anymore a problem (in Visual Studio I can ^KC and a block of text will be // commented)

Comment: While I have given a response to this, my +1 remains, because I hadn't ever thought about the problem and I hated it... Now I don't hate it anymore (no more than I hate the shortsightedness of computers :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason why language designers would choose not to
>   implement this?

It makes the lexical analysis more difficult to implement.

> Is it deceptively complex?

IMHO, no, but this is subjective.

> Would it have undesired results?

Hard to tell. You have already discovered that even normal block comments can make problems:

```
/* print ("*/");    */
```

I know 2 languages that have nesting block comments: [Haskell](http://haskell.org) and [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege).

Answer (score 2):

I will make an example and perhaps it will be clearer:

```
/*
    char *str = "/* string";
    // Are we now 1 level inside a comment or 2 levels?    
*/

printf("Hello world. Will this be printed? Or is it a comment?");

/*
    char *str2 = "string */";
*/
```

You couldn't parse comments inside a comment without interpreting what is inside the comment. But you can't interpret what is inside a comment because it's a comment, so by definition "human text" and not "language".

Comment: To expand on this: this is decidable after scanning the whole file (or other unit of input), but it would require MUCH more complex lexical scanning.

Comment: @Marcin You could have `*/` inside of strings in another comment... I think it would become complex.

Comment: Don't you get the same problem if you have `/*comment ... code"*/"code */`. I.e. it would be ok, in your example to say you are in 2 levels.

Comment: In you edited example, yes it's a problem, but you still get that problem now, so i don't see why it's more of a problem than existing comments.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett The `/*` is always closed by the first `*/` (even if the */ is in a `"/*"`, so the second one can be parsed by the language and, if it's outside of `"/*"` or `//` comment then it is an error. To be clear, in C# `/* string c = "*/" here it's code, not comment`

Comment: @xanatos: With a scanner that would be aware of quoting contexts. Which is of course why no-one bothers with it.

Comment: @xanatos: That's precisely the point i'm making - comments break already. See my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Although C's multi-line comments can't be nested, the effect of recursive comments can more-or-less be achieved in C using `#if 0 ... #endif` (and I strongly recommend you use that when you want to disable a block of code, for exactly that reason).

Even the C preprocessor, designed to be as dumb as a post, would be perfectly capable of handling nested comments, just as it has to be capable of handling nested `#if` directives with false conditions. So it's not really to do with anything being difficult to define or parse, since although it makes comments more complex, they'd still be no more complex than other things done in preprocessing.

But, using `#if 0 ... #endif` requires of course that there not be any unmatched `#endif` in the code you're trying to exclude.

Fundamentally comments cannot be both (a) completely unstructured and (b) recursive. Either by happenstance or deliberate choice, C has gone with (a) -- commented text doesn't have to obey any syntax constraints other than not containing the comment-terminator sequence (or trigraph equivalent such as `*??/<newline>/`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just never considered to begin with and it becomes a "non-important" feature addition as things develop. Also, it requires a lot more validation.

Example scenario...

**MyLang version 1: Objective**

- Provide Multi-line commenting

Developer: hmmm.. I know, every time I find a `/*` I will comment everything until the next `*/` - easy!

**MyLang version 1 release**

1 day later...

User: erm... I cant do recursive comments, help me.

Support: Please hold.

30 mins later...

Support Manager -> Developer: User cannot do recursive comments.

Developer: (What's a recursive...) hang on...

30 mins later

Developer: yeah, we dont support recursive commenting.